# Javascript function returns time in negative

Tags: javascript

this code returns the time in negative im a newbie in web development, kindly help

```
let countDate = new Date('April 1, 2023 00:00:00').getTime();

function countDown() {

    let now = new Date().getTime();
    gap = countDate - now;

    let second = 1000;
    let minute = second * 60;
    let hour = minute * 60;
    let day = hour * 24;

    let d = Math.floor(gap / (day));
    let h = Math.floor((gap % (day)) / (hour));
    let m = Math.floor((gap % (hour)) / (minute));
    let s = Math.floor((gap % (minute)) / (second));

    document.getElementById('day').innerText = d;
    document.getElementById('hour').innerText = h;
    document.getElementById('minute').innerText = m;
    document.getElementById('second').innerText = s;

}

setInterval(function() {
    countDown();
}, 1000)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUGa5.png)

tried to rectify the code but unable to understand it fully, kindly help what needs to be done in this

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a countdown timer to April 1, 2023. If the countdown is showing a negative time, it means the target date has already passed. Since today's date is April 15, 2023, the countdown will show a negative value because April 1, 2023 is in the past.

Comment: `now` is a bigger number because it is further away from the epoch. You got the subtraction problems backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The countDate variable is set to a date and time in the past

Answer (score 1):

The `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch, which is defined as the midnight at the beginning of January 1, 1970, UTC. (Definition on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime))

Since `April 1, 2023 00:00:00` is in the past, `new Date().getTime()` returns a greater number than `new Date('April 1, 2023 00:00:00').getTime();`, since more milliseconds have now elapsed.

It therefore follows that `countDate - now` is negative.

To fix this, either change your code to `now - countDate` (which will return a positive number for a date in the past) or choose a date in the future for your countdown.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line `gap = countDate - now;`

The `now` date is later than the `countDate`, therefore it's internally represented as a larger number than `countDate`. To fix this, simply reverse the order of the subtraction:

`gap = now - countDate;`

Answer (score 0):

It is because your countdate is less than the current date.
You are counting from `1 apr 2023` but today is `15 apr 2023` , Hence the date is already over you need to keep your countdate greater than today's date `[i.e countdate > 15 apr]` or you can change `gap=now-Countdate`

Answer (score 0):

Your *countdate* is set to past, so it will return *negative* value. I made this **codepen** to add a validation when it finished the countdown, it will return *day:00, hour:00, minute:00* and *second:00* as ypu can see it will 00. Try to change the *countdate(example: April 17, 2023)* to see the result.

```
[Codepen.](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/OJBMBYj)
```